# Proof that $\root \of k$ is irrational.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

There is a proof in my math textbook about the fact that:

> If $k$ is a positive integer that is not a perfect square , then $\root \of k$ is irrational.

**Proof**:

It is easy to see that there exists a positive integer $n$ such that:

$$n^2 < m < (n+1)^2 \to n < \root \of m < (n+1)$$

So , $\root \of m$ is not an integer. $....(1)$

Lets assume that $\root \of k$ is in the form $\frac{p}{q}$ where $p$ and $q$ are coprime integers and $q > 1$. Therfore:
$$ \root \of k = \frac{p}{q} \to k = \frac{p^2}{q^2} \to kq = \frac{p^2}{q}$$

Obviously , $kq$ is an integer but $\frac{p^2}{q}$ is not a integer , because $p$ and $q$ are natural numbers , coprime and $q > 1$. So because of the contradiction,

$$kq \neq \frac{p^2}{q} \to \root \of k \neq \frac{p}{q}$$

So , $\root \of k$ cant be written of the form $\frac{p}{q}$ where $p$ and $q$ are coprime integers and $q > 1$ $ ..... (2)$

From $(1)$ and $(2)$ we can conclude that $\root \of k$ is irrational. $~~~~~~~~~~~\square$

> Is this a valid proof?

Comment: I don't see what $(1)$ has to do with what follows.  The second part looks ok if you are assuming Unique Factorization or something of that form, but you should stress that.  How do you know that $\frac {p^2}q$ is not an integer?  And why doesn't the same argument already apply to $\frac {p^2}{q^2}$?

Comment: Yes, it seems to me like a perfectly valid proof. Do you have any specific qusetions about it?

Comment: The proof is valid , but I agree lulu that the argument that $\frac{p^2}{q}$ cannot be an integer could be worked out more detailed. The last question of lulu's comment is a good one.

Comment: @lulu you need (1) so that you can say $\sqrt{k} = \frac{p}{q}$ with $p,q$ coprime and $q >1$. And from the fact that $q>1$, it follows that $\frac{p^2}{q}$ is not an integer

Comment: But we are starting with the assumption that $k$ is not the square of an integer.

Comment: In fact, the argument could be replaced by : "If $p$ and $q$ are coprime and $q>1$ , then $\frac{p^2}{q^2}$ is a fraction with coprime numbers and the denominator is again greater than $1$. Hence $\frac{p^2}{q^2}$ cannot be an integer." There is no need to multiply with $q$ first.

Comment: @lulu By working with $\frac{p^2}q$ we don't need the full Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, we can just use Euclid's lemma.

Comment: @PM2Ring   No..$q$ isn't a prime (necessarily).  And if you meant to say "we could select a prime $\psi$ dividing $q$ and apply Euclid to that" then, I agree, but of course you could do that with $q^2$ just as easily.  And, more to the point, Euclid's lemma is pretty nearly equivalent to Unique Factorization.

Comment: @lulu Good point about $q$ not necessarily being prime, thanks for the improved version. :) And sure, Euclid's lemma is pretty close to the FTA, and usually invoked in proofs of the FTA.

Comment: "But we are starting with the assumption that k is not the square of an integer." Yes but you need to state why this implies that $\ \sqrt{k}\ $ is not an integer, in order to then use the next bit, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part is not necessary:

> It is easy to see that there exists a positive integer $n$ such that:
>
> $$n^2 < m < (n+1)^2 \to n < \root \of m < (n+1)$$
>
> So , $\root \of m$ is not an integer. $....(1)$

You only need:

By assumption, $k$ is a positive integer that is not a perfect square, i.e. $\ \nexists m\in\mathbb{N}\ $ such that $\ m^2 = k\ $ and by taking the positive square root of both sides, we see that  $\ \nexists m\in\mathbb{N}\ $ such that $\ m = \sqrt{k}. $

$$$$

I actually think the rest of the proof is fine, although [this is where you wrote "obviously"], if you want to be more rigorous, you should *justify why*

> $p$ and $q$ are natural numbers , coprime and $q > 1$

implies that

> $\frac{p^2}{q}$ is not a integer.

You can do this, for example, by writing both $p$ and $q$ in prime factorisation form and applying [Euclid's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma#:%7E:text=Euclid%27s%20lemma%20%E2%80%94%20If%20a%20prime,those%20integers%20a%20and%20b.&text=It%20is%20used%20to%20define,numbers%20to%20arbitrary%20commutative%20rings.).